# Consistency of MLE

Tags: probability-limit-theorems

How to show that if we have a iid $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ of exponential distribution with parametr $\lambda$ then the estimator of maximum likelihood is consistency.
I know that this estimator equals $$\hat{\lambda}_n=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$$
$$P(|\hat{\lambda}_n−λ|>ε)→0 $$
$$P(|\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}-\lambda|> \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$$
any idea?

$EX_1=\frac{1}{\lambda}$
$$P(|\frac{1}{\hat{\lambda}_n}-\frac{1}{\lambda}|> \epsilon) \rightarrow 0$$
but why we can take inverse of this statistics? 
$$P(|\frac{1}{\hat{\lambda}_n}-\frac{1}{\lambda}|> \epsilon) \rightarrow 0=P(|\hat{\lambda}_n−λ|>ε)→0 $$
Is it the same?

Comment: I assume you mean $\hat{\lambda}_n = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$, rather than $\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$. If $z_n$ are positive values that converge to a positive number $z$, then $1/z_n$ are positive values that converge to $1/z$.

Comment: Yes, my mistake $\hat{\lambda_n}=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}$ but why $\frac{1}{z_n} \rightarrow \frac{1}{z}$? Is it any theorem?

Comment: The function $f(z) = 1/z$ is continuous over the domain $z>0$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function  Alternatively you could use $|\frac{1}{z_n}-\frac{1}{z}|= \frac{|z-z_n|}{|zz_n|}$, and if $z_n\rightarrow z>0$ then $z_n>z/2$ for all suffciently large $n$.